# Not able to build and run an ionic and cordova based app on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have a very basic `Ionic` app that I am trying to build and run on a `Win 10` machine. But I am getting following error when I run this command. Not sure that else is missing as I am quite new to `NodeJS` and `Android` technologies.

```
# ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[16:57:21]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[16:57:21]  build dev started ...
[16:57:21]  clean started ...
[16:57:21]  clean finished in 21 ms
[16:57:21]  copy started ...
[16:57:21]  deeplinks started ...
[16:57:21]  deeplinks finished in 26 ms
[16:57:21]  transpile started ...
[16:57:23]  transpile finished in 2.77 s
[16:57:23]  preprocess started ...
[16:57:23]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[16:57:23]  webpack started ...
[16:57:24]  copy finished in 2.94 s
[16:57:26]  webpack finished in 2.57 s
[16:57:26]  sass started ...
[16:57:27]  sass finished in 913 ms
[16:57:27]  postprocess started ...
[16:57:27]  postprocess finished in 10 ms
[16:57:27]  lint started ...
[16:57:27]  build dev finished in 6.43 s
[16:57:29]  lint finished in 2.17 s
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\nital\Documents\Tech\RESET-CODE-SAMPLES\IONIC-CODE-SAMPLES\ionic-basics\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
(node:15236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\nital\Documents\Tech\RESET-CODE-SAMPLES\IONIC-CODE-SAMPLES\ionic-basics\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\nital\Documents\Tech\RESET-CODE-SAMPLES\IONIC-CODE-SAMPLES\ionic-basics\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
(node:15236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Ionic Info**

```
# ionic info
√ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\nital\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.9.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.2.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

**Cordova Requirements:**

```
# cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.4\bin\gradle
(node:10252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
    at C:\Users\nital\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:414:27
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\nital\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at C:\Users\nital\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\nital\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\nital\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\nital\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:10252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10252) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Environment Variables:**

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\jdk
GRADLE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.4
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
Path =  %JAVA_HOME%\bin; %GRADLE_HOME%\bin; %ANDROID_HOME%\bin;
```

**Java Version Info:**

```
# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_181

# java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

I also looked into this online link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/
and after installing Android Studio installed all the required tools and addons (screenshot below)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

So there were two issues here:

1. Incorrect `ANDROID_HOME` env variable value. This should NOT point to where you installed android. The AppData is a hidden folder in Win so you need to find that and then point to the correct path

   ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\nital\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
2. Not pointing `PATH` env variable to `platform_tools` and `tools` folders located within `Sdk` folder

   PATH = C:\Users\nital\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

   PATH = C:\Users\nital\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the android sdk directory in your path.

If you look at the Cordova Requirements log, it says `'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

So you need to add the `tools` and `platform-tools` from wherever the android sdk is installed in your System Path.

Comment: Thanks Sumana, I just added that after looking into some SO links. Let me try again.

Comment: make sure to close the Command Prompt and open a new one after making the changes to your path

Comment: Now when I run command `cordova requirements` command I get `Android target: installed android-28,android-27,android-26` and then when I run `ionic cordova build android` I get `BUILD FAILED in 0s
(node:14976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where: Script 'C:\ionic-basics\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.`

Comment: Do you see any folders inside the ```build-tools``` folder in your android sdk folder?

Comment: Also do you have ```ANDROID_HOME``` in your System Environment variables?

Comment: Yes, I have two folders `27.0.3` and `28.0.2` inside `build-tools` folder and I have `ANDROID_HOME` in my Env variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180479/discussion-between-user2325154-and-sumama-waheed).

Comment: Thanks Sumama for the guidance